# The want of consistency in django models inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, orm, model

Let's consider two simple models (Django v1.5.5 assumed), one inherited from another:

```
from django.db import models

class StreetAddress(models.Model):
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    building_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %d" % (self.street_name, self.building_number)

class Cafe(StreetAddress):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

StreetAddress intentionally created as non-abstract, because i suppose its instances being created independently from the cafe instances or another possible descendants.
Let's try to create some cafe located by some address:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from heir_demo.models import StreetAddress, Cafe
>>> addr = StreetAddress.objects.create(street_name='Piccadilly', building_number=5)
>>> addr
<StreetAddress: Piccadilly 5>

>>> mollys = Cafe.objects.create(streetaddress_ptr=addr, name='Mollys')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  ...  stacktrace goes here ...
Warning: Column 'building_number' cannot be null
```

The question is -- why django requires fields of ancestor model when i specified instance of this model explicitly?

I understand that it could be fixed by a little workaround like this:

```
class Cafe(StreetAddress):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.streetaddress_ptr is not None:
            for field in self.streetaddress_ptr._meta.local_fields:
                if field.name != 'id':
                setattr(
                    self,
                    field.name,
                    getattr(self.streetaddress_ptr, field.name)
                )

        return super(Cafe, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now it works just as expected:

```
>>> from heir_demo.models import StreetAddress, Cafe
>>> addr = StreetAddress.objects.all()[0]
>>> mollys = Cafe.objects.create(streetaddress_ptr=addr, name='Mollys')
>>> mollys
<Cafe: Piccadilly 5>
```

Please, explain me -- why it does not work without any workaround? Isn't it  the most consistent and predictable behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want that kind of behavior, try using `OneToOne` relationship rather than inheritance.

Comment: Yes, it works, but according to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance): The inheritance relationship introduces links between the child model and each of its parents (via an automatically-created OneToOneField). Thus, i see no reasons for another behavior of model inheritance.

Comment: Your model (no pun intended) is flawed. A cafe *is not* a street address, it *has* a street address. Encapsulation, not inheritance.

Comment: Composition! I meant composition! *hangs head in shame*

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I apologize, if this example confuse you, it has been thought up for demonstration purposes only. **The question is -- why django requires fields of ancestor model when i specified instance of this model explicitly?**

Comment: Because **inheritance is a "is a" relation**. You *cannot* separate the two.

Comment: Really? The ancestor model is absolutely all-sufficient and its instances could be created regardless to the descendant model.

Answer (score 0):

I dare to answer by myself. Although, it's likely to be a proposition, rather than an answer.

Here is a little patch for Django v.1.5.x (it also could be easily adapted for the Django master branch).

I propose to replace [these two lines](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/db/models/base.py#L590-L591) in save_base method of django.db.models.Model class
by following code (just an idea):

```
        related_object = getattr(self, field.name)
        if related_object is None:
            self.save_base(cls=parent, origin=org, using=using,
                           update_fields=update_fields)
        else:
            for related_field in parent._meta.local_fields:
                if related_field is not parent._meta.pk:
                    setattr(
                        self,
                        related_field.attname,
                        getattr(related_object, related_field.attname)
                    )
```

This little patch allows to **create an instance of derived model based on the existing instance of the parent model**.

```
>>> from heir_demo.models import StreetAddress, Cafe
>>> addr = StreetAddress.objects.create(street_name='Piccadilly', building_number=5)
>>> mollys = Cafe.objects.create(streetaddress_ptr=addr, name='Mollys')
>>> mollys
<Cafe: Piccadilly 5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proposition would allow the creation of separate objects which share their parent part (consider a model Restaurant which looks just like your Cafe). That is, generally, weird in the object-oriented world, but fine in the relational world.

However, then you'll find yourself where you can have a Cafe and a Restaurant in the same StreetAddress, but not two Cafes nor two Restaurants. And that would be much more surprising than Django's current expectation, that (essentially) every object have its own identity.

Comment: I did not suggest to violate one-to-one relation, on which inheritance is based on. I believe there is no need to worry about possibility of such a violation, because of the unique constraint applied to this foreign key on a DB level. BTW, this example (streets and cafes) is just an example, and it seems to be absolutely inefficient and awkward, taking into account your reaction. Also i suggest to extend, rather than to change, current behavior.

Comment: The unique constraint is enforced in each table separately. If there are restaurants and cafes, no unique constraint will prevent sharing an id between them -- except if you can't suddenly add a cafe on an existing street address; then the unique on street address id handles it.

Comment: Now i see what you meant. Nevertheless, this behavior for some model could be enabled explicitly, in my opinion. Anyway, thank you for explanation.